# Tracking a fragment of a file in two places with git

Tags: git, split

I have code such as

```
void myfunc()
{
  introduction();

  while(condition())
  {
    complex();
    loop();
    interior();
    code();
  }

  cleanup();
}
```

which I wish to duplicate into two versions, viz:

```
void myfuncA()
{
  introduction();
  minorchangeA();

  while(condition())
  {
    complex();
    loop();
    interior();
    code();
  }

  cleanup();
}

void myfuncB()
{
  introduction();
  minorchangeB();

  while(condition())
  {
    complex();
    modifiedB();
    loop();
    interior();
    code();
  }

  cleanup();
  extracleanupB();
}
```

git claims to track content rather than files, so do I need to tell it that there are chunks here that are common to both `myfuncA` and `myfuncB` so that when merging with upstream changes to `myfunc` that those changes should propagate to both `myfuncA` and `myfuncB`? If so, how?

The code could be written so that `myfuncAB` did the correct thing at each point by testing for condition A or B, but that could seriously hinder readability or performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not duplicate code**. That's the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Neither git nor anyone will help you for that.

Besides, you misunderstood the role of git: git tracks *file contents*, not chunks. There is no way to tell git that such and such chunks in one file are the same.

Comment: git tracks *content*, actually. But what you should've emphasized is *tracks*, anyway ;-) It doesn't produce any.

Comment: I didn't ask it to *produce* content :-) I said I wished that it might recognize that I'd copied and pasted content.

Not copying and pasting code is a good idea, but all rules can have exceptions.

Such a git feature would not immediately violate the DRY principle, because there *is* one source of "truth". One problem comes later when some modification to `myfuncA` or `myfuncB` should be made to the other, and isn't made because they're now separated.

Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, git it a great source code management system, but it rarely does programming for you.